# AutoIt IDE with customizable code editor font

Tags: ide, autoit

The default SciTE that goes with AutoIt installation uses shabby little font and it's hurting my eyes.

I tried getting the full SciTE version and it still doesn't have any font customization.

Is there an AutoIt compatible IDE that allows for custom code font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SciTE has font customization. Go to `Options` menu and `Open Global Options File`. It should open `SciTEGlobal.properties` file. Now look for this and change to whatever you want:

```
if PLAT_WIN
font.base=font:Verdana,size:9.4
font.small=font:Verdana,size:8
font.comment=font:Georgia,size:10.1
font.code.comment.box=$(font.comment)
font.code.comment.line=$(font.comment)
font.code.comment.doc=$(font.comment)
font.code.comment.nested=$(font.comment)
font.text=font:Times New Roman,size:11
font.text.comment=font:Verdana,size:9
font.embedded.base=font:Verdana,size:9
font.embedded.comment=font:Comic Sans MS,size:8
font.monospace=font:Consolas,size:8.9
font.vbs=font:Lucida Sans Unicode,size:10
```

Change and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. You will see the changes in real time.

Font name can contain spaces. Here is my setup:

```
font.base=font:DejaVu Sans Mono,size:10
```

Note that changing global options might require to run SciTE as administrator on Windows Vista and newer. Otherwise, you may copy the modified lines in the user options file.